# How can I reload the contents of my quickfix, but with a different errorformat?

Tags: quickfix, errorformat

I use `:make` to run a python script to build a C++ project. Usually, the output errors are C++ errors and `:compiler msvc` parses them correctly. Rarely, the error is a python one and I want [`:compiler python`](https://github.com/idbrii/vim-david/blob/main/compiler/python.vim) instead.

Is it possible to re-parse the quickfix with a different `errorformat` without re-running the command that generated the output?

The best solution I've got is to hope the python lines survived as unrecognized lines (prefixed with `||` and load them out of the quickfix buffer, but this seems brittle:

```
:copen | 0,$yank | new | put | %s/^|| // | compiler python | cgetbuffer | bdelete! | nohlsearch
```

Comment: I think when quickfix throws lines away, they’re gone, but you could use the quickfix functions to process the entries? Or combine the errorformats? (PS :%yank)

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is a special one that is not fully covered by either `:compiler msvc` or `:compiler python` so making your own "compiler" seems to make the most sense. Now, how to go about it?

The `errorformat` set in `$VIMRUNTIME/compiler/msvc.vim` is simply the default one.

The `errorformat` set in your third-party script completely replaces the default value with a custom one.

One thing I would try would be to replace the `=` in:

```
CompilerSet errorformat=%A%\\s%#File\ \"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l\\,\ in%.%#
```

with a `+=` and see how it goes. This would *append* the custom `errorformat` to the default one and, presumably, match both the C++ errors and the Python ones.

The drawback, here, would be that `errorformat` is a rather large comma-seprated list of values that are tried in order, which can give you false positives. Maybe you could identify the value(s) that effectively match *your* C++ errors (say `%f:%l:%c:%m`) and do something like:

```
" in compiler/mine.vim
CompilerSet errorformat=%f:%l:%c:%m
CompilerSet errorformat+=%A%\\s%#File\ \"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l\\,\ in%.%#
etc.
```

Comment: I was hoping for a post-process solution, but I guess that information is lost? This is helpful, but don't I need to explicitly `set efm&` in case `efm` already changed? Also, I don't think I'd want other invocations of python to recognize msvc errors, but I guess I could make a new `compiler/pybuild.vim` that merges the two together with something like: `compiler msvc | let c_ef = &efm | compiler python | let &efm=c_ef ..','..&efm` (maybe needs `unlet current_compiler` too...). Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to copypaste the contents of my (custom) compiler/msvc.vim and compiler/python.vim into another file, so instead I found a solution that combines the C++ and python `errorformat` and uses the python `makeprg`.

Saved as ~/.vim/compiler/py_msvc.vim:

```
" Compiler: python that builds C++ with msvc

if exists("current_compiler")
  finish
endif

" Use :runtime because :compiler makes vim setup CompilerSet which errors if
" it's already setup.
runtime compiler/msvc.vim
silent! unlet g:current_compiler
let c_ef = &errorformat

runtime compiler/python.vim
silent! unlet g:current_compiler

" Prepend so C errors are recognized first.
let &errorformat=c_ef ..','..&errorformat

let g:current_compiler = 'py_msvc'

" vim:set sw=2 sts=2:
```